# Install an Integration Module from Azure Automation onto a VM

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc, azure-automation

I have a VM custom script extension that uses AzureRM.Storage cmdlets. When run, the script fails because it does not recognize the functions. Specificially, this error:

> CommandNotFoundException Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : The term
>   'Set-AzureStorageBlobContent' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

The solution is simple. I need to `Install-Module AzureRM.Storage` on the VM. The problem is that I am working in an environment that should not install from the PowerShell Gallery (or the internet). I need the source to be the list of [Integration Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-integration-modules) in my Azure Automation account.

[image]

In my DSC's, this is handled for me. I can `Import-DSCResource` and it will reach out to the Automation modules and install them in the local module root. How can I do this with a [custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)? I have a DSC the runs before the script extension, so could install the module there but have not found a way yet. The following does not work as it seems the module is only installed once used, not on import.

```
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName AzureRM.Storage
```